# How to determine the (n,m) dimensions of a carbon nanotube?

Tags: nanoscience

I've been reading about nanotubes lately, and I keep seeing the $ (n,m) $ notation. How does this describe a nanotube's structure? How do I determine which is $n$ and which is $m$ ?

I'm familiar with matrix notation referring to rows and columns, but I couldn't connect it with the nanotube structure which is, albeit predictable, not quite like a row-column grid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the picure below, you can see how the row-column grid correspond to the graphene structure.

[image: Graphene structure]

To have a (n,m) nanotube, you "just" have to roll your graphene sheet so that the (0,0) hexagon coincides with the (n,m) hexagon. Of course, it is much easier said than done !

Comment: édéric: Does "coincide" mean that the northwest edge of $ (0,0) $ will merge with the southeast edge of $ (4,3) $, so that it will form a seamless nanotube?

Comment: @Kit : No, the twot northwest edges will merge, as well as the two southwest edges.

Answer (score 4):

A carbon nanotube can be seen as a sheet of graphene that is "rolled up".

Now, graphene is a two-dimensional lattice and hence has two lattice vectors, $\vec{a}_1$ and $\vec{a}_2$. (If you are unfamiliar with lattice vectors let me know and I will expand on this).

The numbers $(n,m)$ simply state that your tube is obtained from taking one atom of the sheet and rolling it onto that atom that is at located $n \vec{a}_1 + m \vec{a}_2$ away from your original atom.

EDIT: Graphene is a *tridiagonal* lattice with two atoms per unit cell.

[image: Left: Lattice structure of graphene, right: Brillouin zone (not of interest here)]

> <sup>Image source: The electronic properties of graphene. A.H. Castro Neto *et al.* [*Rev. Mod. Phys.* **81**, 109 (2009)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.81.109), [arXiv:0709.1163](http://arxiv.org/abs/0709.1163), [U. Manchester eprint](http://www.condmat.physics.manchester.ac.uk/pdf/mesoscopic/publications/graphene/RMP_2009.pdf).</sup>

Comment: +1 The way I understand it, for an ordinary row-column grid, its lattice vectors are $90\,^{\circ}$ apart. How does this generalize to a graphene lattice?

Comment: @Kit : You can have oblique coordinates in the plane. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ObliqueCoordinates.html

Comment: I actually found the image you used in Figure 2 of Neto, et al. _The electronic properties of graphene_. 2009. I think it would be a courtesy to the authors to cite them, and also for me (and others) to help us know the relevant papers to read `:)`